# для чего в canvas нужен toDataURL()?

Tags: javascript

```
toDataURL()
```

для чего он нужен?  Я не могу понять, объясните пожалуйста. Желательно с примером/ Пожалуйста, можете показать пример использования.

Comment: Вы пытались гуглить? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: слушай, если бы я понимал, то не спрашивал тут? верно? Даже после того как гуглил не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просили пример использования...
Пример: нарисовать изображение и задать его в качестве фона страницы.

```js
var canvas = window.document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width  = 100;
canvas.height = 100; 

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke(); 

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

window.document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dataURL + ")";
```

Comment: рили спасибо, что показал как его применять. Да, я тупой и не мог найти статью на русском, ну или хотя бы с примером.